# How to Stop Overriding of Bootstrap Css Styles

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Problem**

I have a stylesheet (bootstrap) that when applied in the header overwrites my personal styles.

I do need these bootstrap styles when the js is invoked otherwise the dialog that pops up is un-styled.

How can I stop my own styles from being overwritten?

Comment: Load the bootstrap css first, then your custom stylesheet.

Comment: You should rather only take the part that you really need. Then you can use the "closest" CSS selectors. One way to make sure that this does not interact with your style sheets is using a prefix for classes.

Comment: @NickR that doesn't work, i think there must be styles that i haven't used my sheet doesn't override them.

Comment: @moose could you explain what you mean by "take the park you really need"? The bootstrap css is 5000 lines of code and has stuff in it i've never seen before, it could take days of trial and error looking for stuff i don't need.

Comment: Do you know the inspector of Chrome or Firebug? With that tool, you can quite easily find styles that get applied to an element you see. Or use a customized version of bootstrap ([Link](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)) (I think it's modal what you need.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand your question fully, but here's what I understood:

1- You are using Twitter Bootstrap in your project, and it is overwriting your stylesheets. 
2- You need bootstrap for a popup dialog and nothing else.

Well, from the first question, you can:

-Call your hand-made stylesheet AFTER calling Bootstrap's css.
-Change your stylesheet CSS classes and ID's.
-Hierarchize your classes from the ID's, for example:

```
#foo{
    color: black;
}
#foo .bar{
    color: white;
}

#foo .bar>li{
    margin: 10px;
}
```

-Add a '!important' after the affected classes (Not recommended at all).

For the second matter, you could:
- Costumize your boostrap, you could pick certain plugins (such as popup), and exclude others that you don't use. ([Costumize Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/))

Comment: yes that is exactly what i need! Thank you soo much, so from what you wrote the bootstrap is a style sheet that has other styles that are not for the popup dialog? I wasn't aware of that and that would explain why it is killing my personal style sheet! OK so i have two possible solutions pick a custom bootstrap or use !important! These sound great! Why just out of interest would you not recommend the use of !important

Comment: @DanCundy Well, the !important could confuse you, in some situations, and it is semantically incorrect, because you are overriding, when you could just avoid it. And yes! Bootstrap is a toolbox, where the popup is just a tool. You can download only what you want/need. Don't forget to set your question as answered!

Comment: @DanCundy And I think it would be for the best to, not only select what you use in bootstrap, but fix your classes orders, so that you don't have any more problems regarding your stylesheets being overrun.

Comment: What do you mean fix my class orders? The order in which my css are referenced in my header? And thank you again by the way for your answer. :)

Comment: @DanCundy If you want, upload a Fiddle with your CSS and HTML, and I'll take a look. Take for example my little snippet up there, You set the ID, it could be your page container, for example, and only then set its children, but always referencing the ID as parent.

Comment: you really don't want to look at my CSS its not organised in any way shape or form and uses no parent/children hierarchy. It's far to gone in my eyes to re-organise it, it works and the benefits don't outway the negatives at this point of the project, as it's almost finished. On my next project i will however structure my CSS and definitely learn from my mistakes made on this project.

Answer (score 0):

Like Nick R mentioned in the comments - Order is important here. The browser will 'overwrite' styles as stylesheets are loaded. For example, if you have two sheets:

```
.darkdiv {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

and then a stylesheet with:

```
.darkdiv {
    color: #888;
}
```

Any element with class "darkdiv", will keep the original background-color but have the grey (#888) colored text as that style was 'overwritten' by the second stylesheet.

Comment: I'm aware of how the sheets work @problemPotato, just the one i need to style a js invoked dialog is 5000 lines of code and i think it must has style that aren't being overided by my style sheet. Thus i was hoping for a way of calling the sheet only when needed then being discarded after?